# VSCode Document Selector for snippets

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to filter the suggested snippets regarding the file path name?

This could be similar to `pattern` parameter for the [Document Selector API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/document-selectors).

For example, I would like to suggest only snippets for `Model` if the current file path matches the pattern `"**models**"`, eg:

- `src/prj/some_app/models.py`
- `src/prj/some_app/models/pizzas.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using user snippets as of VS Code 1.25

However an extension could provide these types of dynamic snippets by implementing a [`CompletionItemProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider) that contributes the snippets